# Jcrop: after setImage jcrop does not take TrueSize when applying new image

Tags: javascript, jcrop

I'm working with Jcrop and trying to fit it nicely in responsive layout. I decided that it will be destroyed on window.resize and reinitialized with TrueSize parameter (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592528/2126308). But now I want to add option to update image by `setImage`, but on small screen after change the img, Jcrop resizing it back to img's original size. Should I destroy Jcrop and reinitialize again(as on resize) or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share with my solution as I had looked into the code of that function which BTW wasn't too long:-) and it turned out that `setImage` function recalculates everything without considering the TrueSize dimensions which were passed on initialization. Only way to resolve this was to add another method to Jcrop. Unfortunately, and correct me if I am wrong, the Jcrop v0.9.12 had not been written to handle function overloading, so I have finished with custom Jcrop.

To be specific, I have changed only the initial size on image laod

```
...
img.onload = function () {
    var iw = img.width;
    var ih = img.height;
    ...
}
```

to

```
...
img.onload = function () {
    var iw = $origimg.width();
    var ih = $origimg.height();
    ...
}
```